# .net MVC4 Form submit generates ? instead of / in url -- wrong routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm kinda new to asp.net mvc4 and try to get some practise now. after some research about routing i still got a problem to pass parameters after a form submit.

my form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Resplaner", FormMethod.Get, new { name = "navigation", id = "navigation" }))
{
    <select name="id" size="15" id="nav_menu">
        @foreach (var categorie in Model.Categories)
        {
            <optgroup label="@categorie.Name">
                @foreach (var ressource in Model.Ressources)
                {
                    if (@categorie.Id == ressource.Type)
                    {
                        <option value="@ressource.Id">@ressource.Name</option>
                    }
                }
            </optgroup>
        }
    </select>
}
```

which is submitted by the following java script:

```
$('#nav_menu').on('click', function (event) {
            if ($(event.target).is("option")) {
                var form = $(event.target).parents('form');
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

my actual routes are configurated like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Resplaner",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Resplaner", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

so my problem is right now that my generated url after the form submit looks like this

`http://localhost:62456/Resplaner?id=6`

but my desired url look should look like this

`http://localhost:62456/Resplaner/Index/6`

if i type the second url manually to my browser, the correct result is shown... thats why i guess there is something wrong in the way how i submit my form. or my routes are still messing up.

i already did some example tutorials about forms in mvc4 but they are always used in a different case like my. so i would be happy about a helping hand.

i am thankful for every help :)

greetings Kurn

Comment: Instead of setting `null` for your action and controller values, actually put those into your `Html.BeginForm()` statement

Comment: you are right, fixed it. but my problem is still the same :)

Comment: My second comment is that your two routes are the exact same.  The defaults will not cause the route engine to choose one over the other.  Delete your second route and let me know the results.

Comment: I thought the default route call the HomeController and the second one the ResplanerController. But i deleted the second route, everything is still correctly navigating. but the url is still written wrong with ? instead of / :S

Comment: What happens if you just use `Using(Html.BeginForm()){` instead of overloading the caller?

Comment: actually the form method is changing automaticly to post if i just use the standard BeginForm. So the form is submitting but nothing is passed `http://localhost:62456/Resplaner` (the result url)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my solution -

Have your html like this -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Resplaner", new { name = "rami", id = "1" }, FormMethod.Get))
{
    // ....
}
```

Then have a route this way -

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MyRoute",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Resplaner", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Then your jquery hits the form submit, your URL is going to be -

[image]

And the URL is going to be - `http://localhost:5738/Resplaner/Index/rami/1?`

**NOTE:** If you do not want that Question mark at the end, then make a POST instead of GET.

The other solution would be to use Hidden Fields -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Resplaner", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.Hidden("id", "1");
    @Html.Hidden("name", "rami");
    <input type="submit" value="click"/>
}
```

But again this approach will give you - `http://localhost:5738/Resplaner/Index?id=1&name=rami`

One more Alternative is to create a `@Html.ActionLink()` with the required URL and make it click in jquery.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. i tried your first solution. the problem here is, that the id is fixed. the result of this solution looks for me like this `http://localhost:62456/Resplaner/Index/1?id=11`. i dont have  the time for more tests today. your last solutions seems to be the best for me. i will go the way with the actionlinks and throw the idea about the form away.

Comment: @KURN, do you have proper routes in place, as shown be me?

Comment: yes i implemented all your code 1:1 to test it. strange for me is that the html source code is changed to this `<form action="/Resplaner/Index/rami/1" id="navigation" method="get" name="navigation">`. but even the actionlink way seems to be the most easy one

Comment: ok i tried your first solution again with the post method. the navigation with the form works now. but the url is still not changing :S no matter which item i navigate, the url is always `http://localhost:62456/Resplaner/Index/1`. The html form code looks like this `<form action="/Resplaner/Index/1" method="post" >` what looks not correct for me, because the /1 schould be dynamic. i really thought i understand the whole routing system in mvc asp.net... but it seems like not :)

Comment: @KURN, it is because I have hardcoded that to `id = "1"`. You have to make it dynamic probably through JS or through ViewBag or so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it on another way.

To fix my actual problem i just added a new action in my Controller which receive the form parameter with the question mark and simply do a redirect to the desired url.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult IndexMap(String id = "1")
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Resplaner", new { id = id });
}
```

It may be not the best way to do it because of the second server call. but for my project i dont see any performance issues since it will be only used in an intranet.

`http://localhost:62456/Resplaner/IndexMap?id=2` will redirect to `http://localhost:62456/Resplaner/Index/2`

I would like to thank everyone who tried to help me. You gave me some great suggestions and ideas.